# Editing pages design on Drupal

Tags: drupal

My sister has a website running on Drupal which i have no experience at all in using. She now wants to edit the design of the frontpage and also so inner but i have no idea how to access the file like "index.html" in a non-Drupal platform.

It has adopted some kind of theme and module (which these two terms puzzled me enough).

May I know how to edit the layout and how to access to the requisite file? thank you...

Comment: It's not a 10 line answer, so I would suggest you read the documentation on drupal.org for theming and then post the problem here which you face in doing that so..

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to get an answer to your question. Your question is basically 'Tell me how drupal works'. Seems like to need to read up a little on how drupal theme layer works.
It also depends on which theme you are using.
Take a look at: http://drupal.org/node/171194